# Ubuntu 14.04 crashes home wifi

Tags: 14.04, networking

After a recent update my computer seems to crash my home wifi if it is turned on and connected for a period of time (a few hours). Yes, I'm quite sure Ubuntu is to blame since it wasn't a problem until a recent update.

The router doesn't crash as such, the SSID is visible for all devices; but all attempts at establishing contact fails for all connected devices. If the computer is turned off the wifi doesn't crash.

My computer is an Asus X53Sv. `lspic` tells me:

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
```

I have installed 14.04.2 Trusty.

My router is an Asus RT-AC68U running *DD-WRT v24-sp2 (04/22/14) std*.

The solution for the time being is turning the router off and on again, but that gets old quite fast.

Comment: I confirm this behavior for some wireless adapters in Ubuntu. It shold be reported as a bug.